# Miss $HOME/.config/git directory

Tags: git

I have no problem when installing and using some basic commands with git but missing $HOME/.config/git directory so I can't try gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it directly:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.config/git
touch $HOME/.config/git/config
```

Make sure you have a recent enough version of git (1.7.12+) to interpret that other global config file.

Comment: I followed your comment but how can I have sub directory such as gitignore http://git-scm.com/docs/ and other parts. Can you show me some document about it??

Comment: @NhanLy gitignore is not a directory. It can be a file: `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`, as explained in http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config